# Cubic fields correspond to $3$-torsion ideals in quadratic fields, or to order $3$ characters of quadratic class groups?

Tags: nt.number-theory, class-field-theory

I was watching [Dick Gross's laudation for Manjul Bhargava](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wfv_RImVdI), followed up by [one of Bhargava's talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4xvYdyqW2s), and I realized I was confused about something.

Bhargava says (around 21 minutes) that the orbits of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on binary cubic forms, meaning cubic forms of the sort $a x^3 + b x^2 y + c x y^2 + d y^3$ with $a$, $b$, $c$, $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, correspond to orders in cubic number fields. A bit later (36 minutes), he says that orbits of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on cubic forms where $3$ divides $b$ and $c$ correspond to a pair of quadratic field $K$ and ideal class of $K$ with cube equal to $1$.

So, up to this issue of divisibility by $3$, orders in cubic fields are ideal classes with cube $1$ in quadratic fields.

But I also know class field theory: Given a quadratic field $K$, and a character $\mathrm{Class}(K) \to \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$, I get an unramified cubic extension of $K$.

So, here is where I am confused:

- The number of cubic characters is the same as the number of order $3$ elements, by the classification of finite abelian groups. But they aren't in natural bijection! Is there some extra structure here which is letting me biject them, so that I can say that the two constructions give the same result?
- Thinking one way, I got an order in a cubic field, but the other way I only got a cubic field. Are the other orders in cubic fields also encoded by some ideal class data?

I don't have a precise question, but what I'm looking for is a statement of how to relate these two descriptions of quadratic fields.

No real motivation here. I just like to understand how things fit together.

**EDIT** Uggh, I should have kept watching rather than pausing this to work on it for a while and then put up this question. Bhargava starts talking about this around 50 minutes.

But, now that I have kept watching, it seems that he still doesn't explain why he is working with $3$-torsion classes, not $3$-torsion characters.

Comment: The fields you get from class field theory are not cubic fields, but certain sextic fields (cubic extensions of quadratic number fields). So I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: Right, but that's practically the same thing. Given a nonabelian cubic field, it's Galois closure is a sextic field of this sort. The sextic fields in question are Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $S_3$ (since $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ acts on $\mathrm{Class}(K)$ by negation, and an extension $1 \to \mathbb{Z}/3 \to G \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 1$ must be semi direct.) Taking one of the three order $2$ subgroups of $S_3$, we get a cubic field.

Comment: Alright that helps, but the Galois closure you get will not be unramified over its cubic subfields. So perhaps you are looking for a correspondence "order in first description" <-> "ramification data in second description"?

Comment: Yes, that might be what I should be asking. Plus my continued confusion about the difference between $3$-torsion classes in the class group and in its dual.

Comment: Say you have a binary cubic form of discriminant $D$. Your 3-torsion ideal class is, considered as a binary quadratic form, basically its Hessian; it has discriminant $−3D$ (up to squares, maybe). So what you are seeing is a actually correspondence between 3-torsion in $C_{-3D}$ and index 3 subgroups of $C_D$. For that, look up ``Scholz reflection.'' Underlying that is actually a duality which explains this.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but it might help. The correspondence between cubic forms and 3-torsion elements in the class group is basically due to Eisenstein. Please take a look at the page 62 of this paper: http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=ensmat-001:2000:46::30.